# how to make openid provider discovery

Tags: openid, openid-provider

how to make discovery for openid provider like for orange.fr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenID uses [YADIS](http://yadis.org) for discovery. You can read how to perform it [here].
However, that method can fail, and in such case OpenID uses HTML discovery, described in the [OpenID specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#html_disco).

That answers your question, but if you want to just use OpenID, you probably should find some [library](http://openid.net/developers/libraries).

Comment: but mewp , orange.fr does not return yadis documnet nor does html contains openid.server or openid2.provider. please  help

Comment: `openid.orange.fr` does.

Comment: in openid.net it is written to login using orange.fr just type orange.fr not openid.orange.fr.the problem is there are 100 of openid provider so for every openid i have make a record of there uri that gives openid.server.how to solve this problem.Please help Mewp.

Comment: I can't help you, because `orange.fr` simply does not have any information about openid. And the fact that `openid.net` states otherwise should not bother you, because it's your users' problem, not yours. If someone uses orange.fr provider, they have to know their url. Unless you make a button "login with orange", in which case you just have to enter another url instead of `orange.fr`, which doesn't seem to be a problem.